# Redirects defined in next.config.js not working on Netlify

Tags: next.js, netlify

I have a monorepo with 2 Netlify websites built using NextJS.
Each of them with their own `netlify.toml`-file in their folder.
I have redirects defined in `next.config.mjs` and it works locally.

[The readme states that I need to configure the `publish` to be the full path of the `.next` folder.](https://github.com/netlify/next-runtime#monorepos)
It's defined with the full path `apps/web/.next` in Netlify UI and the plugin doesn't break, but it also doesn't work.
When I try to define full paths in the `toml`-files, then it uses the path relatively, which repeats the path, and the plugin throws because the folder `apps/web/apps/web/.next` doesn't exist, obviously.

There are no errors or warnings, it just doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?